# SAS Import failing when data not present in file

Tags: sas

I am trying to import a text file which is just having column names separated by tabs but there are no records in the file for a day.

**Below is the logic:**

```
proc import file="/saslocation/Current_Day_Records.txt" out=WORK.VENDOR_RECORDS_BY_DAY
dbms='09'x replace 
;run;
```

**Log:**

```
NOTE: Unable to open parameter catalog: SASUSER.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST in update mode. Temporary parameter values will be saved to 
WORK.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST.
Unable to sample external file, no data in first 5 records.
ERROR: Import unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.
```

Any help to resolve the error is highly appreciated.

Header data in the file: 
Dealer_id  date    Dealer_Sr       Dealer_Quote  Approved_Quotes     Approval_Rate  Dealer_Dues

Comment: If you already know the column names, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to import it that way because SAS searches for data in order to set the column types/formats. If it doesn't have data to look at, it won't be able to set columns to numeric/character.

A better way would be to tell SAS explicitly how to create the columns using infile and the input statement:

```
filename textdata 'saslocation\Current_Day_Records.txt';
data VENDOR_RECORDS_BY_DAY ;
  infile textdata delimiter='09'x MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
input
      Dealer_id :8.
            date         :DATE9.
            Dealer_Sr    :$200.
            Dealer_Quote :$200.
            Approved_Quotes :$200.
            Approval_Rate   :8.
            Dealer_Dues     :8.
    ; 
run;
```

I'm only writing it this way because I'm assuming you might eventually have data in that text file and need to import it this way.. but really, you don't need the infile statement at all if you just need a blank shell of a dataset with header information only. If that's all you need and you have the full list of column names and attributes you want to set them as, you can just as easily do that with proc sql or a data step with no infile statement.

```
    proc sql;
       create table VENDOR_RECORDS_BY_DAY
           (
                  Dealer_id       num
                , date            num format=date9.
                , Dealer_Sr       char(200)
                , Dealer_Quote    char(200)
                , Approved_Quotes char(200)
                , Approval_Rate   num
                , Dealer_Dues     num
                );
    quit;
```

Editing to add: If you REALLY need the column names from the text file (perhaps there are 100 column names or variable column names) then you can do your proc import statement with `getnames = no;` and `datarow=1;` statements added, and then follow an approach similar to this to take that first row of data and reset it as the column names: https://communities.sas.com/message/122471#122471

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly in both the scenarios. When there are 800 records and when the file came blank.